# Why "Fetch as Google" returns Not found from my React app on GCP Storage

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, react-router, google-search-console

I've created my React app by create-react-app.
Then I put it into GCP Storage.
I set website configuration (Main page and 404 page) to index.html.

Folder structure is like this

```
├── asset-manifest.json
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── service-worker.js
├── sitemap.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.****.css
│   └── js
│       └── main.****.js
```

I'm using react-router. The routing is like this

```
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
```

When I checked my app from web browser, it's totally fine.
I can see `www.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com/about`

When I checked by "Fetch as Google", `www.mydomain.com` is ok.
But `www.mydomain.com/about` returns "Not found"

I've checked with Chrome 41 (old version). And I can see `www.mydomain.com/about`

Does anyone know why I'm getting not found?
Which part should I check?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while trying to deploy my app to GitHub Pages. I decided to deploy my app using [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) because netlify has an option to prerender. Now "Fetch as Google" recognizes the routes.

My App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import 'babel-polyfill';

import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Navbar from './components/CustomNavbar';
import Footer from './components/footer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```